# Hosting Django server on FTP space

Tags: python, django, ftp

I have built a Django project which I'd like to deploy now. I've already tried deploying it on pythonAnywhere which worked. But, my college wants to host it on their server and they have given me some server space and FTP credentials to upload files there. How can I get my Django website on to my college's server and host it from there?

Comment: You cannot do this; you need to be able to run scripts on the server.

Comment: What type of serve it is? CentOS, Ubuntu, Redhat, Windows? Which version? You will need more than FTP.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, most popular pattern is to use Nginx and Gunicorn. Gunicorn to run your Django app and Nginx to serve as a reverse proxy for Gunicorn. You need something like Gunicorn, a WSGI compatible application server to serve your Django app. Otherwise, I don't think that's possible.

Read more about how to deploy a Django app here: [Deploy a Django app to Digital Ocean](http://rahmonov.me/posts/deploy-a-django-app-to-digitalocean/)